# Many-One Self Join - rails own docs wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The rails docs are apparently in error  - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#selfjoins)

> In designing a data model, you will sometimes find a model that should
>   have a relation to itself. [...]

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :subordinates, :class_name => "Employee"   
  belongs_to :manager, :class_name => "Employee",
    :foreign_key => "manager_id" 
end
```

> With this setup, you can retrieve @employee.subordinates and
>   @employee.manager.

---

Actually, in at least the console, an error is generated in the above if foreign_key is not "employee_id".

Here's my specific code:

```
#Table name: plates
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  datetime   :datetime
#  parent_id  :integer
#  precision  :integer
#  tags       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#

class Plate < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :templates

  has_many :children, :class_name => "Plate"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Plate",
    :foreign_key => "parent_id"
  [...]
```

...and the query I run:

```
irb(main):002:0> Plate.find_by_name("blog090822").children.first
```

If I run that it generates SQL looking for plate_id and then returns an error for non-existant column.  If I change the column  name to plate_id through a migration, reseed the DB and rerun the query it works.

If this *is* a rails documentation error, how commonplace is that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [API documents](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to), there are some explanations to `foreign_key`. For `belongs_to`:

```
By default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix.
```

For `has_many`:

```
By default this is guessed to be the name of this class in lower-case and “_id” suffixed.
```

So in your case, the `foreign_key` for :children should be `plate_id`, and the `foreign_key` for :parent should be `parent_id`.
To let your code work while keeping the data schema, only the `foreign_key` for :children is necessary, which override the default `foreign_key` with `parent_id`.

The code in the Rails guide could be wrong.